# conditional expectation, exercice:difficult calculus

Tags: probability

Let $\mu,\alpha_n:\mathbb R^+\to \mathbb R$ continuous function with $\mu$ bounded function.
Let $N^{(n)}$ the trajectory of a Poisson process with intensity $\alpha_n \mu$.
Let $0=T_0^{(n)}<T_1^{(n)}<..$ jumps of $N^{(n)}$

Let $M_n(t)=\sum_{i=1}^{N_t^{(n)}} \frac {1} {\alpha_n (T_i^{(n)})}$

Calculate $E(M_n(t)|N_t^{(n)})$

My idea:
$E(M_n(t)|N_t^{(n)})=E(M_n(t)|N_t^{(n)}=u)=E\left(\sum_{i=1}^{u} \frac {1} { \alpha_n (T_i^{(n)})}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{u}E\left(\frac {1} { \alpha_n (T_i^{(n)})}\right)$

But then I don't know. Can you help me?

Thank you

Comment: Are the subscripts and superscripts with "$n$" really necessary? They seem to be a distraction.

Comment: What is $\alpha_n \mu$? Does this mean an inhomogeneous Poisson process with intensity that varies with time according to $\alpha_n(t)\mu(t)$?

Comment: For a time-homogeneous Poisson process with constant rate $\lambda$, if you condition on having $u$ arrivals during $[0,t]$, their locations are independent and uniformly distributed over that interval.  I am not familiar with the corresponding result for inhomogeneous Poisson processes with rate $\lambda(t)$, but I _strongly suspect_ that their locations are again independent and identically distibuted, but with a possibly nonuniform location distribution with density $f(x) = \frac{\lambda(x)}{\int_0^t\lambda(u)du}$ for $x \in [0,t]$.  Can you solve based on that?

Comment: I have a formula:
L=law L(T_1,..,T_n|N_t=n) has for density:
$g_n(t_1,...,t_n)=\frac{n!} {h(t)^n}\lambda(t_1)...\lambda(t_n)1_{0<t_1<..<t_n \leq t}$ with $h(t)=\int_0^t \lambda(s) ds$ and $(N_t)$ is a Poisson process with intensity $\lambda$ But I don't see the link with my exercice

Comment: In other words, based on my comment above, given the number of arrivals during $[0,t]$ is $u$, the arrival times $\{X_1, .., X_u\}$ are independent and identically distributed with PDF $f_X(x) = C\lambda(x)$ for $x \in [0,t]$, where $C$ is a constant that makes the PDF integrate to 1. This fact is easier to use, as the joint PDF you gave requires the arrival times to be ordered $T_1\leq T_2 \leq .. \leq T_u$, whereas mine does not require this ordering and results in simple iid properties.

Comment: If you really want to use your joint PDF then you do the multi-dimensional integral: $$ E\left[\sum_{i=1}^u \frac{1}{\alpha(T_i)}\right] = \int ... \int g(t_1, ..., t_u)\left(\sum_{i=1}^u\frac{1}{\alpha(t_i)}\right)dt_1...dt_u$$  I do not recommend this approach since it gives an ugly integral, although in the end it can be simplified to what I was saying before.

Answer (score 1):

For a Poisson process the times *between* jumps, $T^{(n)}_{k}-T^{(n)}_{k-1}\ ,$ are independent and exponential distributed random variables. This implies that individual jump times are sums of independent exponential random variables, hence they are Gamma-distributed. $$T^{(n)}_{k} = \left(T^{(n)}_{k}-T^{(n)}_{k-1}\right) + \left(T^{(n)}_{k-1}-T^{(n)}_{k-2}\right) + \cdots + \left(T^{(n)}_{1}-T^{(n)}_{0}\right)\ ,$$ noting that $T^{(n)}_{0} = 0 \ .$